# JqPlot - Different colors for LINE and FILL how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I have been strugling trying to achieve something like this:

[Check charts line and fill colors](http://connect.garmin.com/activity/518207083)

This is exactly what I need. Do you know how to make line and fill colors different?

Thanks

This is how I have my script:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#btnResetHeartRateZoom').show();
        var data = [@string.Join(",", Model.Activity.Laps.SelectMany(t => t.TrackPoints).Select(h => h.HeartRate))];
        var HeartRatePlot = $.jqplot('HeartInformation', [data],
            {
                seriesColors: ['#85802b'],
                title: "@Resources.HeartRate",
                axesDefaults: { labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer }, //Render de los textos.
                series: [{ showMarker: false, fill: true, color: '#FCB1B8' }], //Para no mostrar markers.
                axes:
                {
                    xaxis: { autoscale: true, label: "@Resources.Distance", pad: 0 },
                    yaxis: { autoscale: true, label: "@Resources.HeartRate [bpm]" },
                },
                highlighter: { show: true, sizeAdjust: 7.5 },
                cursor: { show: true, zoom: true }
            });

        $('#btnResetHeartRateZoom').click(function () { HeartRatePlot.resetZoom(); });
    </script>
```

This is my result:

[image: This is my plot]

Comment: What have you tried so far? And, how have your efforts differed from the desired result?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that. Check my settings. I tried different series however no luck :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an individual [`Series`](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Series), you can enable [`fillAndStroke`](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Series.fillAndStroke) to draw both the fill and line:

> If true will stroke the line (with color this.color) as well as fill under it.  Applies only when fill is true.

With [`fillColor`](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Series.fillColor) specifying a 2nd color:

> CSS color spec to use for fill under line.  Defaults to line color.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rjDgh/

```
series: [
  { ..., fill: true, fillAndStroke: true, color: '#FCB1B8', fillColor: '#ccc' }
]
```

Comment: One last question, is there a property to define how thick the line would be? FOUND IT:  seriesDefaults: { lineWidth: 1.5, },